# Separating Top And Bottom Menu Containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem I am having is that the div for the main site content is using the entire webpage, when however I want it to start below the top nav bar. This results in some content of the page being cut of by the top nav bar.

Here we see the top nav bar is taking up the right amount of screen http://prntscr.com/gty4u9

But here we see the rest of the page is taking up everything, when I want it to take up everything but the top menu.  http://prntscr.com/gty54s

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand title" href="#">DSUM</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{username}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li ><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.well -->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <br>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <a class="visible-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-reorder"></i></a>
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

            </div>
            <!--/row-->
        </div>
        <!--/span-->


    </div>
    <!--/row-->

    <hr>



</div>
<!--/.container-->
```

Here is my CSS

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

footer {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/*
 * Off Canvas
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row-offcanvas {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        background: #ecf0f1;
    }

    .row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -40%;
    }

    .row-offcanvas-left.active {
        left: 40%;
    }

    .sidebar-offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 40%;
        margin-left: 12px;
    }
}

#sidebar {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.title {
    background-color: #1F70A8;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e1ffff;
    width: 185px;
}

.sidebar-item-group {
    color: #637083;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for the sake of more semantic HTML, start using tags like `<nav>`, `<main>`, `<header>` etc.

To solve your problem, just add `padding-top` to your `<main>` tag (container for the rest of your webpage) that is equal to the `height` of your navbar..

Even bootstrap documentation recommends this solution for their navbar, even though I think they already have created a class for it, I think it's called `page-header`.. so if you areusing bootstrap, just do that...

**[Edit]** Actually after looking at boostrap documentation, if you using their framework, all you need to do is to add class `.navbar-static-top`

Comment: Yeah I thought about the padding, I just thought they may have a been a more proper way but if bootstrap recommends it then yeah I'll do it.

Comment: Well it's one line of code, hardly you will find something neater :) and as padding uses same fixed height as navbar, there's no way you could get unwanted results on different devices :)